# KiiObject Upload Picture to use for profile

Tags: java, image, android-studio, kiicloud

I am a web dev and a couple of weeks ago I started trying to learn android studio and app dev. Im currently using [kii cloud](http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/android/) for my android app and I am currently trying to figure out how implement the following scenario --

a. I already have user registration, so I am currently working on a "edit profile" page.

b. On the edit profile page Im trying to create a button so that the user clicks on it and it will then open a fragment where the user can upload the image. [link](http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/android/managing-users/user-attributes/)

c. Then attach that image to the url, and use the URL where needed such as a view profile page. link[enter link description here](http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/android/managing-data/object-storages/)

**EditUserProfile.java**

```
public class EditUserProfile extends Activity {
    Button picbutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        picbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MypicButton);

        // Capture button clicks
        picbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragcon);
        if(fragment == null)
            fragment = new ProfilePic();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragcon, fragment);
        ft.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**ProfilePic.java (Fragment)**

```
public class ProfilePic extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ProfilePic";
    String objectUri = null;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private Activity activity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attach_file, container,
                false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        objectUri = args.getString("object_uri");
        Button attachButton = (Button) view
                .findViewById(R.id.attach_file_button);
        attachButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onAttachFileButtonClicked(v);
            }
        });
        setPageImage(3);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.details);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.activity = null;
    }

    public void onAttachFileButtonClicked(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            String filePath = getFilePathByUri(selectedFileUri);
            Log.v(TAG, "Picture Path : " + filePath);
            if (filePath == null) {
                showAlert("File not exists, Please select an image that exists locally.");
                return;
            }
            uploadFile(filePath);
        } else {
            showToast("picking file failed!");
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this.activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private String getFilePathByUri(Uri selectedFileUri) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            // Workaround of retrieving file image through ContentResolver
            // for Android4.2 or later
            String filePath = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        this.activity.getContentResolver(), selectedFileUri);

                String cacheDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "app";
                File createDir = new File(cacheDir);
                if (!createDir.exists()) {
                    createDir.mkdir();
                }
                filePath = cacheDir + File.separator + "upload.jpg";
                File file = new File(filePath);

                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.getFD().sync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                filePath = null;
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Nothing to do
                    }
                }
            }
            return filePath;
        } else {
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = this.activity.getContentResolver().query(
                    selectedFileUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            if (cursor == null)
                return null;
            try {
                if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
                    return null;
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                if (columnIndex < 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                return picturePath;
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadFile(String path) {
        KiiObject object = KiiObject.createByUri(Uri.parse(objectUri));
        File f = new File(path);
        Log.v(TAG, "file can read : " + f.canRead());
        KiiUploader uploader = object.uploader(this.activity, f);
        uploader.transferAsync(new KiiRTransferCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStart(KiiRTransfer operator) {
                setFragmentProgress(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransferCompleted(KiiRTransfer operator, Exception e) {
                setFragmentProgress(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (e == null) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void moveFromDialogFragment(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this.activity, clazz);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    void showAlert(String message) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
                R.string.operation_failed, message, null);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    void setFragmentProgress(int v) {
        ProgressFragment fragment = (ProgressFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.progressFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.setProgressBarVisiblity(v);
        }
    }

    void setPageImage(int page) {
        ProgressFragment fragment = (ProgressFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.progressFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.setPageImage(page);
        }
    }
}
```

Then for things like this, Im trying to find a way to dynamically show the profile pictures associated with the users, and if not use the icon as default.

```
holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_account);
```

**UserListLoader.java**

```
public class UserListAdapter extends AbstractArrayAdapter<IUser> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.image_list_item);
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        IUser user = this.getItem(position);
        holder.position = position;
        holder.text.setText(user.getUsername());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_account);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Also when opening in app, the EditUserProfile crashes at 
   **picbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()**

Any guidance or help on the matter is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of exceptions? If it is NullPointerException, please check your `<button>` tag has `MypicButton` id correctly.

Comment: It's very hard to follow the whole thing. I advice you partition the problem into small problems an post one by one. Note that you can also get specific Kii help on community.kii.com

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helped someone...

public void uploadImage() {

```
        UserFields userFields = new UserFields();
        userFields.putDisplayName("AllDeals");

        KiiUser.registerAsPseudoUser(userFields,
                new KiiUserRegisterCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRegisterCompleted(KiiUser kiiUser,
                            Exception exception) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (exception != null) {
                            // Error handling
                            Log.e("Exception", exception.toString());
                            return;
                        } else {
                            String accessToken = kiiUser.getAccessToken();

                            final KiiObject object = Kii.bucket("AllDeals")
                                    .object();

                            object.set("placeImage", imageURL);

                            File localFile = new File(picturePath);
                            KiiUploader uploader = object.uploader(
                                    getApplicationContext(), localFile);

                            uploader.transferAsync(new KiiRTransferCallback() {
                                public void onTransferCompleted(
                                        KiiRTransfer operator,
                                        Exception exception) {
                                    if (exception != null) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    object.publishBody(new KiiObjectPublishCallback() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onPublishCompleted(
                                                String url,
                                                KiiObject object,
                                                Exception exception) {
                                            if (exception != null) {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            object.set("url", url);
                                            object.save(new KiiObjectCallBack() {
                                                public void onSaveCompleted(
                                                        int token,
                                                        KiiObject object,
                                                        Exception exception) {
                                                    if (exception != null) {
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    Toast toast = Toast
                                                            .makeText(
                                                                    MainActivity.this,
                                                                    "Your image is added successfully",
                                                                    500);

                                                };
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                };
                            }); 
                        }

                });

}
```